# How to pass text as cell reference in excel?

Tags: excel, reference, cell, vlookup

I have a vlookup which gives an output Sheet2!A:B. I want to use this sheet reference as an argument in another Vlookup as:

```
Vlookup(something, Sheet2!A:B,something, something)
```

I want the second Vlookup to use that as a cell reference. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If the first [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) is returning the literal string *"Sheet2!A:B"* then wrap it in the [INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd) to convert text that looks like a cell range reference into an operational cell range reference. Example:

```
=VLOOKUP(1, Sheet1!A:Z, 26, FALSE)   ◄ returns the text string "Sheet2!A:B" (sans quotes)
=VLOOKUP(<something>, INDIRECT(VLOOKUP(1, Sheet1!A:Z, 26, FALSE)), 2, FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just cascade the *Lookups*  In this example, the first look-up in cell **B2** finds the name of a happy person in table **C1:D5**.

The second look-up uses the result of the first to find the happy person's score in **C7:D11**

[image]